# Datatables and Highcharts - table.on('draw' and function chartData(table)

Tags: javascript, highcharts, datatables

I managed to buid a Highcharts more or less the way I wanted based on a table that is similar to what I can get through Datatables, see [working example](https://jsbin.com/tikixiq/edit?html,js,output).
Unfortunately, when I link the Highcharts to my Datatables, the Highcharts is blank, probably beccause I am missing the

```
table.on('draw', function () {
});
```

and the

```
function chartData(table) {
}
```

parts of my js, as described [here](https://datatables.net/examples/api/highcharts) or [here](https://datatables.net/blog/2020-10-01).

Would you know how I could write these parts to fit my case? I don't need to count, sum or average the data, but just read the value in the Datatables.

Comment: Hi @NALL, Could you reproduce the problem in some online code editor? It seems that your question is specific to the datatables not to Highcharts.

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek. What do you mean by online code editor? Did you have a look to the "working example" abobe mentioned? My question is related to highcharts as well because this is what I need to fix. it is blank.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I've added a solution below.

Answer (score 0):

You can build Highcharts series structure based on datatables. For example:

```
const table = new DataTable('#example1');
const chart = Highcharts.chart("container", {
  chart: {
    type: "line"
  },
  title: {
    text: "Test Data"
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
  },
  series: chartSeries(table)
});

table.on('draw', function() {
  chart.update({
    series: chartSeries(table)
  }, true, true);
});

function chartSeries(table) {
  const series = [];
  // Count the number of entries for each office
  table
    .rows({
      search: 'applied'
    })
    .data()
    .each(function(rowData, a, b) {
      const xData = rowData[0];

      rowData.forEach((data, index) => {
        if (index) {
          if (!series[index - 1]) {
            series[index - 1] = {
              name: $(table.column(index).header()).html(),
              data: []
            };
          }

          series[index - 1].data.push({
            name: xData,
            y: parseFloat(data.replace(/,/g, ''))
          });
        }
      });
    });

  return series;
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jtxw8b5d/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update